# Как лучше добавлять класс в div на чистом JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Как лучше добавлять класс в `div` на чистом JavaScript (без jQuery)?

Comment: Закрывашки, не наглейте. Нормальный вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Element.classList**

*Синтаксис*

> var elementClasses = elem.classList;

**Методы**

1. ***add***( *String* [,*String*] )
   Добавляет элементу указанные классы
2. ***remove***( *String* [,*String*] )
   Удаляет у элемента указанные классы
3. ***item*** ( *Number* )
   Результат аналогичен вызову сlassList[Number]
4. ***toggle*** ( *String* [, *Boolean*])
   Если класс у элемента отсутствует - добавляет, иначе - убирает. Когда вторым 
   параметром передано *false* - удаляет указанный класс, а если *true* - добавляет.
   Если вторым параметром передан undefined или переменная с *typeof* == '*undefined*', поведение будет аналогичным передаче только первого параметра при вызове ***toggle***.
5. ***contains*** ( *String* )
   Проверяет, есть ли данный класс у элемента (вернет *true* или *false*)

> конечно же, у *ClassList* есть заветное свойство **length**, которое возвращает количество классов у элемента.

```js
const elem = document.querySelector("#clock")

//Выведем классы
console.log(elem.classList); //DOMTokenList ["example", "for", "you"]

//Добавим классы
elem.classList.add("ok", "understand");
console.log(elem.classList); //DOMTokenList ["example", "for", "you", "ok", "understand"]

//Переключим классы
elem.classList.toggle("you");
elem.classList.toggle("he");
console.log(elem.classList); //DOMTokenList ["example", "for", "ok", "understand", "he"]

//Проверим класс
console.log(elem.classList.contains("example")); //true
console.log(elem.classList.contains("lol")); //false

//И удалим классы
elem.classList.remove("example", "for", "understand", "he");
console.log(elem.classList); //DOMTokenList ["ok"]
```

```html
<div id="clock" class="example for you"> </div>
```

> *все взято из [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) кому не лень можно и здесь смотреть

Comment: Стоит упомянуть, что classList работает в IE начиная с 10 версии, но для поддержки старых версий есть [Polyfills](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#classlist). Другой вариант добавить класс элементу: `var d = document.getElementById("div1");
d.className += " otherclass";`
Тот же вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element

Answer (score 1):

Свойство classList возвращает псевдомассив DOMTokenList, содержащий все классы элемента.

```
item.classList.add('newClass'); // назначаем новый класс
```